# getJson from integer object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

```
var data={
    "394": {
        "auther": "ushyne",
        "category": "softball",
        "imgSrc": "sd",
        "votes": 0
    },
    "395": {
        "auther": "ushyne",
        "category": "softball",
        "imgSrc": "",
        "votes": 1
    }
};
```

How we can show category, imgSrc value?
Please reply me Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you want to display it? what is the required markup?

Comment: for(var key in data) {
   alert(key.votes);
}

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qv8VT/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
data["394"].category;
data["395"].imgSrc;
```

Comment: not working please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  var data={
    "394": {
        "auther": "ushyne",
        "category": "softball",
        "imgSrc": "sd",
        "votes": 0
    },
    "395": {
        "auther": "ushyne",
        "category": "softball",
        "imgSrc": "",
        "votes": 1
    }
};


for(var key in data) {
    alert(data1[key].category)   ;
data1[key].imgSrc;
}

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways. 
The restriction in your case is that you can't do `data.395` since it is a number, instead use brackets `[]`.

For example you could do :

```
data["395"]["imgSrc"]
data["395"].imgSrc

for (prop in data) {
 console.log(data[prop].imgSrc);
}
```

Comment: A key that begins with a number will need to come in square bracket notation. I.E: `data.395.imgSrc` is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since 394 and 395 are numbers you need to access them with [].

```
console.log(data[394].category);
```

Here is a jFiddle to play around and see other results.

http://jsfiddle.net/sNYXh/

Answer (score 0):

```
var data={
    "394": {
        "auther": "ushyne",
        "category": "softball",
        "imgSrc": "sd",
        "votes": 0
    },
    "395": {
        "auther": "ushyne",
        "category": "softball",
        "imgSrc": "",
        "votes": 1
    }
};

for (var i in data) {
 alert(data[i].imgSrc);
 /*OR*/
 console.log(data[i]); // for all 
}
```

Comment: @user2661652, ok great..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data["345"]["category"]
```